# Using Breeze in a multi page application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, breeze

I'm trying to get an MVVM setup going for a ASP.NET MVC 4 application I'm working on. Recently I ran into the excellent presentation/code-sample from John Papa (which can be viewed here http://www.johnpapa.net/recent-presentation-on-spa-basics/).

He talks about having a jquery/knockout.js/breeze.js software stack, but only in the context of a Single Page Application (SPA).

Looking through the code- I see that a bootstrapper.js neatly sets up the bindings for all views.

```
ko.applyBindings(vm.sessions, $(app.viewIds.sessions).get(0));
ko.applyBindings(vm.speakers, $(app.viewIds.speakers).get(0));
ko.applyBindings(vm.session, $(app.viewIds.session).get(0));
```

If I were to have more cshtml files, to split the views in a more complicated application, how could I elegantly handle the boot strapping as navigation happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use several options (off the top of my head) to link in other views of html:
1) @Html.Partial 
2) [Knockout External Templating plugin](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine)
3) Custom AJAX to go grab the HTML for the views
4) Templating engine of your choice to grab it
5) RequireJS and its text plugin
6) Load them all in 1 page (icky for anything of size)

IF you have Knockout already,. you may want to use the Knockout external templating plugin. Its great for pulling in remote HTML. If you have require.js going already, the text plug in is very nice too.

Comment: With respect to the require/text approach, you should take a look at [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/). You're likely to hear more about that soon.

Comment: @John Papa It sounds like with require.js/text.js we can cleanly "bundle" views and viewmodels together, which would help keep complexity in check as we scale the application. I've read some about Backbone.js as well, but then it starts getting in to a discussion between MVC vs MVVM. My personal experience has been where in ASP.NET MVC 4, with ~10 views, the logic got spread across "ui models", controller and views, which violates proper separation of concerns. I've also worked on a Silverlight 5 project with MVVM and having more views (~35) was more manageable compared to the MVC project.

Comment: I've seen it both ways. I agree that you concerns over separation are valid. There are many separation patterns for JavaScript. AMD and require.js help facilitate those quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You can still have it as a SPA, but separate all your "pages" into separate cshtml files, and then load them in in your index.cshtml using Html.Partial:

```
 @Html.Partial("_Substation")
 @Html.Partial("_Location")
 @Html.Partial("_Weather")
 @Html.Partial("_RealTimeValues")
 @Html.Partial("_EventView")
```

All those strings are the names of my separate cshtml files, but it is still a SPA.

Unless there's another reason that you want to not have a SPA?

Comment: This is a good idea to separate out the code into different files, which is one if the goals. But still doesn't prevent loading all content up front. Maybe as you click around the partials can be loaded, but coming from the Silverlight MVVM world, that sounds like an icky solution.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how much html you're talking about. In the SPA I've just finished, the html with those 5 partial views is 3 KB out of a total of 1.1 MB, once minify and gzip do their magic. I don't load the data for each of the partial views at the start. So I would question exactly how big an overhead it really is to load all the html up-front, especially when you're using knockout to generate a lot of the repetitive html for you.